# Latest version of JSON-Framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json

I am looking for the latest version of JSON-Framework for ios 5.0. I like this becouse is very easy to use (you can see [here](http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c))
I have found this but in the oficial web, all is deprecated.
([Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1VBe.png), i can post any image yet)

Any idea?

Comment: Their Google Code page says: *[This project has moved to GitHub](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSON-Framework is available on Github here, and it is still being updated](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/)

But you don't need to use it ion iOS 5 at all, because Apple introduced native JSON parsing using the `NSJsonSerialization` class [(documentation here)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Most developers would recommend moving to Apple's native implementation unless you had a specific reason for not doing so, and then falling back to a library like JSON-Framework for older OS versions.

Comment: Wow! i don`t know about the NSJsonSerialization class... i will test in a few days!